# Writing a shell in C: How to get pid of running process

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to write a shell in C.

And now i want to make shell catch the signal of suspend, and suspend the running process, but i am not sure which function can return the pid of running process. Currently, i know proc/pid has status info of process, but I don't think scanning all processes to find running status is a good idea. So anyone can give me a hint?

Also I don't know if `waitpid` works for me, but from my understanding, `waitpid` is supposed to keep waiting until the child process stops, and this will never tell me if it's still running, am I right?

Comment: _...not sure which function can return the pid of running process. Currently, i know proc/pid..._ - I guess you know the pid from that statement

Comment: Install a `SIGCHLD` handler using `sigaction()` and the `SA_SIGINFO` flag. That way you'll receive a signal when a child process is stopped (suspended). The child's PID is in `info->si_pid`. If the child process exited, `info->si_code == CLD_EXITED`. If `info->si_code == CLD_STOPPED`, then `info->si_status` tells the signal number that stopped/suspended the process. The rest of the codes are described in the [`man 2 sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) man page. [...]

Comment: [...] You can also use [`waitpid(childpid, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to check if child process with PID `childpid` is running, stopped/suspended, or exited/killed, without blocking. If it returns zero, then examine the `status` int using the `WIF*()` macros etc. as described on the [`man 2 waitpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) man page.

Comment: @NominalAnimal  thank you for your answering, so I add my code now, and I saw you said use WIF to examine status, but I read the man page, maybe because my english is not that well, but most wif macros is focus on if proc is terminated or exit normal, it cant tell me if it still running or sleep, so may you explain more details? thank you,

Comment: Use `int status;` and `pid_t p = waitpid(childpid, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);`. Then, if `p == 0`, the process `childpid` is running. If `p == -1`, examine `errno`: if `errno == EINTR`, a signal was delivered which interrupted the call; redo the waitpid() call. If `errno == ECHILD`, either process childpid is not our child, or has already exited (and been reaped). All other `errno` values are unexpected, and should be treated as fatal errors. Only if `p == childpid` do you examine `status`. If `WIFSTOPPED(status)`, childpid is stopped/suspended. [...]

Comment: [...] If `WIFCONTINUED(status)`, childpid was continued/resumed by a signal. If `WIFEXITED(status)`, childpid has exited (and this waitpid call reaped it, so the childpid PID may be reused). If `WIFSIGNALED(status)`, the child process was killed by a signal.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thank you very much about your explanation. and I have one more question that is getpid will give me the right pid? I use the errno to check error, but i used getppid and getpid into waitpid(), and i ran the code, give it a long proccess time cmd, and i hit ctrlz, errno said no child process. so im wondering that getpid cannot give me the right pid?

Comment: No. `getpid()` always returns the PID of the current process (the process that calls `getpid()`), and `getppid()` returns the PID of the process that created the current process (the parent process). You need to keep track of the child process PIDs yourself, from the moment you call `fork()` to create one.